# Increment value in useEffect() in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I'm developing my first ReactJS app. In the following code, `count` value is not changing in the 2nd Axios post method-

```
export default function Dashboard(props){
   const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

   useEffect(()=>{
    let postData = new FormData();
    postData.append("eiin", eiinNo);
    Axios.post("url",postData).then(response=>{
        if(response.data){     
        }
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error);
    });


    Axios.post("another-url", postData).then(response=>{
        const items = response.data;
        items.map(item=>{
            setCount(count => count + 1);
            console.log(count); //count remains 0, but 2 items here.               
        })
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error);
    });

  },[]);
}
```

What did I wrong here?

Comment: it seems like your axios post "another-url" didnt retrieve any data which is why the counter wasnt incremented

Comment: @zS1L3NT Some data is there.

Comment: I expect setCount won't take effect until a re-render happens.

Comment: State updates are asynchronous, you can't `console.log` after a "setState" and expect to see the updated value.

Comment: `setCount` is async so on the next line it may not be updated. If you want to use the updated value of `count`, add a `useEffect` with `count` as a dependency

Comment: @tanmay would you please show an example? I am completely new in reactjs world.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have mentioned, the setCount function here will queue up an update to the component's state so that when the component next renders it will have a count with the new value. It will also trigger a re-render of the component at a later time with the new count value available.

In this code:

```
        items.map(item=>{
            setCount(count => count + 1);
            console.log(count); //count remains 0, but 2 items here.               
        })
```

The count value will not have changed yet because setCount won't be applied until later.

If you put `console.log(count)` after `const [count, setCount] = useState(0);` you should see the count being updated.

Additionally (I think) that calling setCount multiple times is possibly not ideal, although (I think) react will queue all these updates and run them all at once before re-render, it's still probably better to call it once with the amount that you want it to change by.

Comment: Because setCount is asynchronous, the count will only be updated on re-render (which it will trigger). If you put a console.log(count) after `const [count, setCount] = useState(0);` you should see count getting updated. (Which is true for your example too.)

Comment: What should be the solution in my case?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. If you want a new count available in the map function, then my guess is that you should be able to use a local_count variable, as my previous version of this answer has.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment above, `setCount` is async so on the next line it may not be updated. If you want to use the updated value of `count`, add a `useEffect` with `count` as a dependency.

Here's how it would look like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(count); // here you should get the updated value of count
}, [count])
```

Here's an [example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-rubin-ryf2f?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This creates an infinity loop and my browser gets hang.

Comment: @s.k.paul did you check the example sandbox? it's not going in infinite loop there

Comment: Because you are not incrementing count here.